# VBA: Loop over Items in Dictionary with an Object Variable

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I am trying to loop over the items in a dictionary with an object variable that refer to inheritance class "Breed", but I am unable to do so with dictionaries but with collections it is pretty simple is there a way to solve this without using the dictionary's keys? because then I will lose the ability to use the intelisense feature.

Here is the code of the class Breed:

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Name() As String
End Property

Public Property Get Color() As String
End Property

Public Property Get Price() As Double
End Property
```

Here is the code for class  Dogs:

```
Option Explicit

Implements Breed

Private pName As String, pPrice As Double, pColor As String

Public Property Let Name(Val As String)
    pName = Val
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property

Private Property Get Breed_Name() As String
    Breed_Name = Name
End Property

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Property Let Price(Val As Double)
    pPrice = Val
End Property

Public Property Get Price() As Double
    Price = pPrice
End Property

Private Property Get Breed_Price() As Double
    Breed_Price = Price
End Property

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Property Let Color(Val As String)
    pColor = Val
End Property

Public Property Get Color() As String
    Color = pColor
End Property

Private Property Get Breed_Color() As String
    Breed_Color = Color
End Property
```

Here is the code for class Cats:

```
Option Explicit

Implements Breed

Private pName As String, pPrice As Double, pColor As String

Public Property Let Name(Val As String)
    pName = Val
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property

Private Property Get Breed_Name() As String
    Breed_Name = Name
End Property

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Property Let Price(Val As Double)
    pPrice = Val
End Property

Public Property Get Price() As Double
    Price = pPrice
End Property

Private Property Get Breed_Price() As Double
    Breed_Price = Price
End Property

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Property Let Color(Val As String)
    pColor = Val
End Property

Public Property Get Color() As String
    Color = pColor
End Property

Private Property Get Breed_Color() As String
    Breed_Color = Color
End Property
```

Here is the code for the regular module with collection but fails with dictionary:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Dim C           As Cats
    Dim D           As Dogs
    Dim Coll        As Collection
    Dim B           As Breed

    Set C = New Cats
    C.Name = "Catomon"
    C.Color = "Angle White"
    C.Price = 800.98

    Set D = New Dogs
    D.Name = "Dogomon"
    D.Color = "Golden White"
    D.Price = 1000.23

    Set Coll = New Collection
    Coll.Add C
    Coll.Add D

    Set B = New Breed

    For Each B In Coll
        Debug.Print B.Name, B.Color, B.Price
    Next B

    Set C = Nothing
    Set D = Nothing
    Set B = Nothing
    Set Coll = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to loop through the `.Keys` of the dictionary.

Comment: Hi, I know how to loop through keys, but that require a variant declaration, I was hoping to loop over dictionary with object variable that can provide intelisense's help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary methods `.Keys()` and `.Items()` return arrays. Only way to iterate over arrays is with an variable of type `Variant`. With these restrictions, the only way I can think of is casting Variant variable to the type `Breed` inside the loop. This way, after the casting, you get Intellisense.

Based on the code you posted, an example would be:

```
Sub MainWithDictionary()

    Dim C           As Cats
    Dim D           As Dogs
    Dim Dict        As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim B           As Breed
    Dim K           As Variant 'new variable

    Set C = New Cats
    C.Name = "Catomon"
    C.Color = "Angle White"
    C.Price = 800.98

    Set D = New Dogs
    D.Name = "Dogomon"
    D.Color = "Golden White"
    D.Price = 1000.23

    Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    'Keys are just placeholders
    Dict.Add 1, C
    Dict.Add 2, D


    For Each K In Dict.Items()
        'Cast the Variant result to Breed
        Set B = K
        'You will have Intellisense on each dictionary items after this

        Debug.Print B.Name, B.Color, B.Price
    Next K

    Set C = Nothing
    Set D = Nothing
    Set B = Nothing
    Set Dict = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Nuri, it makes sense.